# How to establish basic html and css structure in modern webdesign?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, containers

As non expert, I'm trying to work my way to define my own style in coding.
Speaking of responsiveness and modern webdesign, is it a good practice to establish a general div container (or wrapper) for all content, or is it better to leave the screen as the main parent?

Answer (score 1):

There really are no general rules or suggestions about such things. It depends on what kind of site you are building, what tools you are using, and how you organize your css. I usually do use a `<div id="wrapper"></div>` around everything, but when I use handlebars templates, or a framework such as ember or backbone I don't do that.

The main rule to follow with any kind of coding is to stay DRY - "Don't repeat yourself." If you find yourself repeating similar lines of code (in any language). That is a good sign that you should rethink the way you are writing your code.

As long as you stay dry, and keep your code looking clean and readable, you can pretty much do anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the structure of the site you're building, however you should never include elements that you don't need.

For regular web design I always use wrapper-type elements on my content to a.) center it, and b.) restrict its maximum width with `max-width` while keeping it responsive.

Occasionally I let my wrappers be children of other elements so that their `background` spans across the entire screen, while the content doesn't.